# MySQL a table must have at least one column

Tags: c++, mysql

At a bit of a loss today completing this application. I need to create a table that has an arbitrary name with defined columns and datatypes. In MySQL shell the command completed successfully, however querying the database in C++ does not create the table. Same command, MySQL Shell succeeds, C++ Connector returns "a table must have at least one column". Here is the code below.

```
// Function to create a table in MySQL
string CreateTable(string book_name, string author)
{
     MYSQL* conn;
     MYSQL_ROW row;
     MYSQL_RES* res;
     string query;
     string query2;
     int queryState;
     int count = 0;

     string table_name = book_name;

     // Make all characters lowercase

     conn = mysql_init(0);
     conn = mysql_real_connect(conn, "localhost", "username", "password", "temp", 3306, NULL, 0);

     if (conn)
     {
          cout << "Connection to database successful..." << endl;

          query = "USE temp;";
          query2 = "CREATE TABLE ";
          query2 += table_name;
          query2 += "(chapter LONGTEXT, page_number INT, paragraph INT, b_text TEXT);";
          cout << "query2: " << query2 << endl;
          cin.get();
          queryState = mysql_query(conn, query2.c_str());

          if (queryState != 0)
          {
               cout << "Error 1: " << mysql_error(conn) << endl;
               cin.get();
          }

          return table_name;
     }
     else
     {
         // Unable to connect to the database
         cout << "Unable to connect to the database..." << endl;
     }
     return table_name;
 }
```

Comment: Just to make sure, since it is not shown, you are certain that the provided book_name parameter is a legal SQL identifier?

Comment: What is the use of this line? `query = "USE temp;";`

Comment: What is the value returned in `queryState`? Is it `1` or `-1` or some other non-zero integer value?

Comment: @kiner_shah `USE` is how you select a default database in MySQL.

Comment: But he never executes `query`, so it seems superfluous.